# addEventListener and removeEventListener different behaviour in Firefox/Chrome vs Edge

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events, microsoft-edge, addeventlistener

I recently ran into a strange inconsistency in the way Edge executed a piece of Javascript compared to Chrome and Firefox.

When attaching a click handler (the wrong one, on accident), Edge reacted as one might expect. But Chrome and Firefox ignored the wrong click handler, hiding my error.

```js
button.addEventListener("click", functionOne);

function functionOne(e) {
  console.log('functionOne called');
  functionTwo(e);
}

function functionTwo(e) {
  console.log('functionTwo called');
  
  // My intial mistake was here: According to my application logic, 
  // I should have removed the event listener for functionOne. Whoops.
  button.removeEventListener("click", functionThree);
  
  console.log("Doing some asynchronous work...");
  
  // Same here: I should have re-added the event listener for functionOne
  button.addEventListener("click", functionThree);
}

// This function is never called by FF and Chrome, but it is called in Edge
function functionThree(e) {
  console.error('functionThree called');
}
```

I intended to remove the event listener for `functionOne` while I was doing some asynchronous work, then reattach once the async call was completed. My mistake was calling `removeEventListener()` with a reference to the wrong function (`functionThree`), then attaching another event listener to `button` which also calls `functionThree`.

But strangely, the code worked as intended in Chrome and Firefox. Only when I tried it in Edge, did I notice that Edge was calling `functionThree`, while Chrome and Firefox were ignoring it.

**Can someone explain this behaviour?** Why do Chrome and Firefox not call `functionThree` although I attached an event listener? Why *does* Edge call it?

Browser versions:

```
 FireFox  59.0.2
 Edge     41.16299.371.0 
 Chrome   66.0.3359.139
```

**TL;DR** - Firefox/Chrome did not attach an event listener as I would have expected. Edge did.

[Link to jsbin example](https://jsbin.com/sovoqubeno/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

From my observations, the difference stems from the fact:

- In BOTH chrome/firefox and ie, an added eventListener will not fire for the current event, but the next event.
- In chrome/firefox removed event listener immediately prevents the handler to be called WHEREAS in ie, handlers already attached on the element will fire, but the effect of `removeEventListener` will take place at the **next tick** of the engine.

This is why, in BOTH cases (ie and firefox/chrome), the first click will not fire function-3, but the subsequent clicks will be fired in ie. To remedy this behavior my solution is to add to ie `stopImmediatePropagation`:

```
function functionTwo(e) {

  console.log('functionTwo called');

  // My intial mistake was here: I put functionThree in by accident
  // and only then noticed the strange behaviour
  button.removeEventListener("click", functionThree);

  console.log("Doing some asynchronous work...");

  // Same here: I should have put functionOne as the second argument
  button.addEventListener("click", functionThree);
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

Now ie will behave like firefox/chrome.